# Pass by reference is not working in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

I am passing object to a class and make some changes in object but at actual objects remain same.

For Example:

```
public class Xclass
{
   public var counter:int=1;
}

private function mymethod(x:Xclass):void
{
   x.counter = 10;
}
```

after come out of this method value of counter is still 1 not 10.

Is there any problem in my code. or is there any other way of passing objects by reference.

Comment: I've been working with AS3 for a year now, and I had no idea this could happen.

Comment: There's something else wrong, cause this should most definitely work. Try out for yourself: https://gist.github.com/creynders/5169757

Comment: Post more code, from how do you initialize your variable that you are passing to the output point.

Comment: more code would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work fine in AS3, take a look in this code bellow:

Main Class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class TesteCake extends Sprite
    {
        public function TesteCake()
        {
            var xclass:XClass = new XClass();
            trace(xclass.getCounter());


            changeCounterXClass(xclass);
            trace(xclass.getCounter());
        }

        private function changeCounterXClass(xclass:XClass):void{
            xclass.setCounter(10);
        }
    }

}
```

It's XClass.as (This class is in other .as file)

```
package
    {
        public final class XClass
        {
            private var counter:int = 1;


            public function setCounter(value:int):void{
                counter = value;
            }


            public function getCounter():int{
                return counter;
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this could help you!